# Where has M365 Owners domain group gone?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, groups, m365

In the past when you created a new SharePoint online site a domain group for the m365 group members and owners would be added to respective SharePoint groups on the site.

Now it seems the owner group has disappeared. How can we configure a site so that m365 owners and members have different permissions in SharePoint? Without having to define unique site level permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The M365 Owners group is added in the SharePoint Owners group. However it is hidden by default.

Follow below steps to show the M365 group:

1. Go to SharePoint Owners group page, click the **List Settings** under settings section:

   [image]
2. Scroll down to the "Views" section and select the default **Detail View**:

   [image]
3. Remove all filters from this "Detail View":

   [image]

   Like this:

   [image]
4. Click "OK" at the bottom of view settings page to save the changes

Now, go back to SharePoint Owners group. The hidden M365 Owners group will be shown in the SharePoint Owners group:

[image]

**Note**: By default M365 Owners group is also added in "Site Collection Administrators" section:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!